# Why are Groups not added to my ListView?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, dictionary, listviewitem

With this code:

```
Dictionary<int, String> PlatypusAccountsDict = PlatypusSetupData.getPlatypusAccountsForCustomer(kvp.Key);
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> entry in PlatypusAccountsDict) {
    int PlatypusAccountNumber = entry.Key;
    string PlatypusAccountName = entry.Value;

    ListViewGroup PlatypusAccountGroup = new ListViewGroup(PlatypusAccountName, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    {
        Tag = PlatypusAccountNumber,
        Header = PlatypusAccountName
    };
    listViewCustomerDuckBillAccountsClients.Groups.Add(PlatypusAccountGroup);
. . .
```

...I can step through and see that there are values in "entry," yet no group is added to my ListView - it's still naked as a jaybird after this code runs. I know there are three possible reasons for this problem: 1) I forgot a step. 2) A gigantic EMP from the sun has broken something, or 3) Something else I'm unaware of.

### UPDATE

Adding this test code after the call to Groups.Add(PlatypusAccountGroup):

```
ListViewItem listViewItem1 = new ListViewItem(new string[] { "Banana", "a" }, -1, Color.Empty, Color.Yellow, null);
ListViewItem listViewItem2 = new ListViewItem(new string[] { "Cherry", "v" }, -1, Color.Empty, Color.Red, new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, ((System.Byte)(0))));
ListViewItem listViewItem3 = new ListViewItem(new string[] { "Apple", "h" }, -1, Color.Empty, Color.Lime, null);
ListViewItem listViewItem4 = new ListViewItem(new string[] { "Pear", "y" }, -1, Color.Empty, Color.FromArgb(((System.Byte)(192)), ((System.Byte)(128)), ((System.Byte)(156))), null);

listViewItem1.Group = PlatypusAccountGroup;
listViewItem2.Group = PlatypusAccountGroup;
listViewItem3.Group = PlatypusAccountGroup;
listViewItem4.Group = PlatypusAccountGroup;

this.listViewPlatypusAccounts.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] {listViewItem1,
listViewItem2,
listViewItem3,
listViewItem4});
```

...DOES add the group I want/expect, but none of those fruity items are added beneath it.

Comment: Have you set the listViewCustomerDuckBillAccountsClients.ShowGroups to true

Comment: @HatSoft: Yep, it's already true; maybe that's the default value for that property, because I don't recollect setting it.

Comment: Add a ListViewItem, set its Group property.

Comment: @Hans: Updated (appended to) my question.

Comment: Can't repro.  I created a Test group, added your listview items, and my ListView control displays a "Test" group with the four items underneath it.

Comment: @Lars: Thanks for that. Back to the coding board.